# Javascript/Node file upload; req.files == null or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, upload

So the only change between using the express-fileupload middleware is that req.files == null instead of undefined (`req.files` is undefined when I'm not using express-fileupload, I don't think I need to be using it though?). Obviously the server script stops at `excel = req.files.myFile.path;` as it can't read property `myFile` of null nor undefined. I'm at a loss here - I'm pretty sure it's an issue with my front end script but I'm not very well versed in ajax and the combination of native JS and JQuery might be screwing me?

```js
//Front end:

  var App = {};
  
  App.handleFileUpload = function handleFileUpload(event) {
   var files = event.target.files;
   var myFile = files[0];
   that.sendFile(myFile);
   }  
  $('#fileUpload').on('change', function(event) {
   App.handleFileUpload(event)
   },
  sendFile = function sendFile(file) {
   var uri = 'http://MYIP/getsheet';
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var fd = new FormData();
   xhr.open('POST', uri, true);
   fd.append('myFile', file);
   xhr.send(fd);
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    var log = xhr.responseText;
    makeDivs(JSON.parse(log));
    console.log(log);
    
    }
   }

   });
      
//Server:

const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const path = require('path');
const ce2j = require('convert-excel-to-json');
const moment = require('moment');
const fu = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(fu());
var log;

app.post('/getsheet', function(req, res){
 console.log(req.files);
    excel = req.files.myFile.path;
   etc...
```

```html
 <body>
  <input type ="file" name ="excel" id="fileUpload" />

   <div id = "main"></div>
        
    </body>
```

I have tried with both `<form enctype>` set and without and it doesn't make any difference (I don't think it should either?).

Comment: as per the express-file-upload no property of req.files.filename.path...

Comment: Yes except it's not getting to that because it's breaking at the `myFile` property.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: ..."as it can't read property myFile of null nor undefined". I also don't think I should need the middleware to achieve this however disabling express-fileupload renders files == undefined instead of null.